# Jquery .apply() not a function error, from instantiated object

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object, instance

I have an object that I am trying to instantiate so I can create different instances of it, that checks against different Regex patterns.

On input + blur the input gets either a success/error class depending if the regex pattern is matched.

I have tried everything I possibly know, but it says 
"Uncaught TypeError: ((r.event.special[g.origType] || {}).handle || g.handler).apply is not a function"

LINK to code example = [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gjpfkcup/2/)

This is the raw js only:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    validate();

function validate() {
    var RegexCheck = (function(window, undefined) {
        this.check = function check() {
            validator = {
                email: /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,                    
                text: /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/
            };
            var isEmpty, pattern, result, elem = this.value;
            isEmpty = !elem;
            pattern = validator.email;
            result = pattern.test(elem);
            if (result === false || isEmpty) {
                $(this).removeClass('success');
                $(this).addClass("error");
            } else {
                                    $(this).removeClass('error');
                $(this).addClass("success");
            }
        };
        return check;
    })(window);

            // Instansiate RegexCheck
    var RegexCheckEmail = new RegexCheck();
    RegexCheckEmail.pattern = validator.email;
    console.log("RegexCheckEmail.pattern = " + RegexCheckEmail.pattern);
    //Change value of 'pattern'
    RegexCheckEmail.pattern = validator.text;
    console.log("RegexCheckEmail.pattern = " + RegexCheckEmail.pattern);

    //$('form#form1 [type=email]').on('input blur', RegexCheck); //works
    $('form#form1 [type=email]').on('input blur', RegexCheckEmail); //doesn't work

    console.log(RegexCheckEmail instanceof RegexCheck); //true

    var RegexCheckText = new RegexCheck();
    RegexCheckText.pattern = validator.text;
    console.log("RegexCheckText.pattern = " + RegexCheckText.pattern);
    $('form#form-1 [type=text]').on('input blur', RegexCheckText); //Seems like I can instaniate from RegexCheck but just does not seem to work
}
});
```

Comment: The second parameter for `.on()` expects a function.

Comment: It seems like there are a bunch of patterns being attempted here that are used incorrectly and are unnecessary. Why not simplify the code by just writing only what you need?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I did pass a function, method from object = RegexCheck and RegexCheckEmail

Comment: @KevinB not sure what else to do with the return, I am wrong in thinking that return check; is ok, is my understanding is it is returning the method.

It works when I call the master object, but not on an instantiated instance of the master object. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: An instance of a class isn't a function. What is an event binding supposed to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not understand clearly how classes and objects work.

The function you have first is a constructor, it should define which properties and methods the object has, there is no sense returning `check` from it (or return anything else as it will not be used as regular function).
See more about objects and constructors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS.

The event handler expects the function, and you are passing the object (`RegexCheckEmail`).
So the first fix is to pass the function into the event handler and not the object.

Next you do some assignments like `RegexCheckEmail.pattern = validator.email`, which does not make much sense. 
You just add the new `pattern` property to `RegexCheckEmail` object, this is not the same as `pattern` variable that is used inside the `check` function.
And the `validator.email` also only exists inside your `check` function.
Instead of these assignments you should use the object constructor to pass the parameters.

See below the working example, it is close to the idea you try to implement in your code, but it is simpler and, I hope, clearer.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  validate();
    
    function validate() {
    
        validator = {
            email: /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
            text: /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/
        };
    
        function RegexCheck(pattern) {
            this.pattern = pattern;
            
            this.check = function check(input) {
                var isEmpty, pattern, result, elem = input.value;
                isEmpty = !elem;
                result = this.pattern.test(input.value);
                if (result === false || isEmpty) {
                    $(input).removeClass('success');
                    $(input).addClass("error");
                } else {
                    $(input).removeClass('error');
                    $(input).addClass("success");
                }
            };
        };
        
        var regexCheckEmail = new RegexCheck(validator.email);
        $('#exampleEmail').on('input blur', function() {regexCheckEmail.check(this)});

        var regexCheckText = new RegexCheck(validator.text);
        $('#exampleText').on('input blur', function() {regexCheckText.check(this)});
 }
});
```

```css
.container{margin-top: 50px;}

.error{
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.success{
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    
      <form id="form1">
     
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleEmail">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleEmail" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleText">Text only</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleText" placeholder="Text only">
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </form>
        
    </div>
</div>
```